# Setting up an Appfabric Cluster - need some clarification

Tags: appfabric

There's something that's not very clear to me and does not show up in the documentation:
After successfully setting up a Cache Cluster with 2 hosts, what is the address for connecting to this cluster? I know this screams setting up a Windows Cluster all over but I just wanted to make sure there wasnt anything I'm missing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no 'address' as such, as you might expect in a load-balancing scenario, but you specify host(s) in the `hosts` section of the `dataCacheClient` config element:

```
<dataCacheClient … >
  <hosts>
    <host name="server1.mydomain.local" cachePort="22233" />
    <host name="server2.mydomain.local" cachePort="22233" />
  </hosts>
</dataCacheClient>
```

Comment: If one of the servers goes offline, does this piece of code know how to cycle between them?

Comment: This _config_ just lists the servers - the cluster, uses the concept of "lead hosts": how this works exactly depends on whether you are using a [high-availability cluster](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790974%28v=azure.10%29.aspx), and what you are using as your [cluster configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790910%28v=azure.10%29.aspx), there's an [overview here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790895%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood your question. The default port to connect to on of your cluster nodes is 22233. [Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx) is an example. You can build up the connection within the code or by putting the cache host configuration into your Web.config file.

Comment: I'll rephrase.
If I have server1 and server2 configured in a cache cluster, what would be the connection string I place in the code? I obviously cant rename it back and forth between server1 and server2 if one of them drops, right? There must be some main computername that is "shared" by the two just like in a real cluster.